# FastAPI shared HttpClient slow response time

Tags: python, fastapi

I have an endpoint which just make a request and returns the response of that request.

Instead of attacking my other server with new connection I thought having a shared HttpClient would be a great idea in FastAPI.

```py
httpx_client = httpx.AsyncClient()
session = requests.Session()
session.mount("http://", HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=1000, pool_maxsize=1000))
aiohttp_session = aiohttp.ClientSession()

def get_requests_session():
    yield session

async def get_aiohttp_session():
    yield aiohttp_session

app = FastAPI()
router = APIRouter()

# slow response time(40ms), reuses session
@router.get("/funtime")
async def search(
    query: str,
    limit: int,
    fa_response: Response,
    session: aiohttp.ClientSession = Depends(get_aiohttp_session),
):
    args = {"q": query, "limit": limit, "attributesToRetrieve": ["id", "title"]}
    url = config.base + "/indexes/pages/search"
    try:
        async with session.post(url, json=args) as response:
            if response.status != 200:
                raise HTTPException(status_code=response.status, detail="Error fetching data")
            return await response.json()
    except Exception as e:
        fa_response.status_code = status.HTTP_300_MULTIPLE_CHOICES
        return {"error": str(e), "url": url}

# slow response time (40ms), reuses session
@router.get("/funtime6")
async def search6(query: str, limit: int, fa_response: Response):
    args = {"q": query, "limit": limit, "attributesToRetrieve": ["id", "title"]}
    url = config.base + "/indexes/pages/search"

    try:
        response = await config.config_httpx_client.post(
            config.clerk_search_url + "/indexes/pages/search", json=args
        )
        if response.status_code != 200:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=response.status_code, detail="Error fetching data")
        hits = response.json().get("hits", [])
        return {"results": hits}

    except Exception as e:
        fa_response.status_code = status.HTTP_300_MULTIPLE_CHOICES
        return {"error": str(e), "url": url}

# fast response time (6ms), new session for each request
@router.get("/v3/test/funtime9")
def search9(query: str, limit: int, fa_response: Response):
    args = {"q": query, "limit": limit, "attributesToRetrieve": ["id", "title"]}
    url = config.base + "/indexes/pages/search"

    try:
        response = requests.post(url, json=args)
        if response.status_code != 200:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=response.status_code, detail="Error fetching data")
        hits = response.json().get("hits", [])
        return {"results": hits}
    except HTTPException as e:
        fa_response.status_code = status.HTTP_300_MULTIPLE_CHOICES
        return {"error": str(e), "url": url}

app.include_router(router)
```

It doesn't matter if I use the Depends(get...) arguments or directly accessing. The response-time of FastAPI increases from 6-8ms to 30-50ms.

This is also with a "high" throughput of more than 10-50 requests a second.
With lower RPS the difference is much smaller between creating new sessions or reusing.

I'm not exactly where the fault is at? It is just python being slow at context switching?
For comparison using rust/go reusing a httpclient is even faster than creating new ones.

I have also tried to just have one endpoint, only one async, only one non-async etc.
Tried putting the clients in their own file.

Some resourses I've used to try and fix this issue:

- [How can I send an HTTP request from my FastAPI app to another site (API)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63872924/how-can-i-send-an-http-request-from-my-fastapi-app-to-another-site-api)
- https://kisspeter.github.io/fastapi-performance-optimization/index
- https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/
- [how do you properly reuse an httpx.AsyncClient within a FastAPI application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71031816/how-do-you-properly-reuse-an-httpx-asyncclient-within-a-fastapi-application)

None of which talk about latency increase (no numbers published at all)

EDIT:
Python version 3.11.6
Tested with Sanic, similair results.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804) answer yout question?

Comment: Sadly not, tried that and the numbers are exactly the same.
Think just has to do that a shared client gets locked in some way when being accessed to fast.

Have tried Py3.10, Py.3.9, exact same behaviour/

Thanks for the resource!